# iOS can we reuse a NSTimer

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, timer, nstimer

I want to use an NSTimer (or if you have a better suggestion) to play a sound when the device is unplugged, or unknown. However if the user plugs the device back in, the sound should immediately stop.

Here's my code but it doesn't seem to behave as I am describing it,

```
- (void)currentBatteryState
{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    switch(device.batteryState) {
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown:
            currentBatteryStatusLabel.text = @"Unknown";
            if ([batteryControlTimer isValid]) {
                [batteryControlTimer invalidate];
                batteryControlTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(playSound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            } else {
                batteryControlTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(playSound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            }
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged:
            currentBatteryStatusLabel.text = @"Unplugged";
            if ([batteryControlTimer isValid]) {
                [batteryControlTimer invalidate];
                batteryControlTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(playSound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            } else {
                batteryControlTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(playSound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            }
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging:
            currentBatteryStatusLabel.text = @"Charging";
            [batteryControlTimer invalidate];
            break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateFull:
            currentBatteryStatusLabel.text = @"Full";
            [batteryControlTimer invalidate];
            break;
    }
}

- (void) playSound
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"siren_1", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Using the same variable (batteryControlTimer) without having to create a new one. batteryControlTimer is in the h file and we synthesized the property in the implementation file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condition isn't met, don't play any sound, but don't invalidate the timer. That way it will keep firing at the interval even if the condition isn't met once.

So:

```
- (void)playSound {
    if(conditionIsMet) {
        //code to play your sound
    }
}
```

Edit:

If you want to make the interval at which the sound can stop because the condition isn't met, then you just need to make the timer's time interval and the duration of the sound smaller.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You want to stop the sound while it's being played back if the condition changes?

Comment: Yes I want to start and stop the sounds based on the condition

Comment: Is it a good idea to put the logic in the playSound code instead of wrap the playSound within the logic?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you should do. Wrapping the logic in `playSound` will let you reuse the timer.